# После удаления значений из таблицы ,новым значениям присваиваются следующие id

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удалил все данные из таблицы ,после этого добавил новые, но отсчёт id начался с 146(перед удалением последний id был 145). Скажите какое свойство или sql-запрос нужно сделать ,что бы отсчёт начинался с 1)

Comment: `Truncate table <tableName>` перезапустит нумерацию с 1

Comment: Да, спасибо, но он одновременно и удаляет все данные из таблицы, а мне нужно что бы они остались.

Comment: Это правильное поведение. Если вам встретится когда-нибудь БД, которая переиспользует айдишники, бегите от неё как от огня!

Answer (score 0):

так не может быть

```
ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> AUTO_INCREMENT=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь еще указать в настройках в самом PHP MYSQL, там в "операции" есть (см пункты сверху). Там можно указать с какого ID ввести отсчет. По моему так проще всего, когда данные/таблицу по сути нужно заново вести.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]